# Cloning Git Repositroy using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone, gitolite

I am trying to clone a git repository on Mac via ssh.
Steps I have followed so far

1. Created `id_rsa.pub` and shared it with the Admin for access.The file is located at `/Users/admin/.ssh`
2. Created a `config` file at `/Users/admin/.ssh`. The file content is

   ```
   Host MY_DOMAIN
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
       IdentitiesOnly yes
   ```
3. I am running the following command on terminal

   ```
   git clone git@MY_DOMAIN:android.git     
   git clone git@MY_DOMAIN:android
   ```

and the response I am getting is

```
Cloning into 'android'...
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Connection to MY_DOMAIN closed by remote host.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am bit confused on, if I am following the right approach or is there any issue with access rights.

Comment: Please show the gitolite configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 steps should be followed for your own user account, and not for `/Users/admin`.

---

Based on your recent edit, it appears that the issue is not with git configuration, but with your gitolite setup. Currently, your gitolite instance is allowing you access to only one repository, namely `testing` as is clear from the following output:

```
hello onkar, this is git@m running gitolite3 v3.6.2-12-g1c61d57 on git 2.1.4

 R W    testing
```

Configure your gitolite-admin repo and allow access to the `android` project as well.

Comment: that is the user through which I have logged in my system ie local mac system

Comment: @onkar Do a `ssh -v git@MY_DOMAIN`

Comment: Thanks for your support hjpotter92, I was not having the appropriate privileges